# Getting Null in all column for Snowflake even though data is present

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

[image: Select * from table_name].I am working on a Snowflake table. I am getting a Null value on every column even though data is present in JSON. Can you please help me on this issue.

```
create or replace external table "database_name"."schema"."TABLE_Name" 
(Name varchar(20) as ( value:Name::varchar), 
Surname varchar(20) as (value:Surname::varchar),
City varchar(20) as (value:City::varchar),
Country varchar(20) as (value:Country::varchar),
Age varchar(20) as (value:Age::varchar),
date_part date as to_date(split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 2)
|| '/' || split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 3)
|| '/' || split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 4), 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
partition by (date_part)
location = @stage/logs/
file_format = parquet;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSON properties are case sensitive. If you specify a nonexistent property name it will return null. Correcting the case for the JSON properties should fix this.

```
create or replace external table "database_name"."schema"."TABLE_Name" 
(Name varchar(20) as ( value:NAME::varchar), 
Surname varchar(20) as (value:SURNAME::varchar),
City varchar(20) as (value:CITY::varchar),
Country varchar(20) as (value:COUNTRY::varchar),
Age varchar(20) as (value:AGE::varchar),
date_part date as to_date(split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 2)
|| '/' || split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 3)
|| '/' || split_part(metadata$filename, '/', 4), 'YYYY/MM/DD'))
partition by (date_part)
location = @stage/logs/
file_format = parquet;
```